# Return different viewmodels in desktop and mobile versions for the same action in zend framework

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework2, user-agent

In my zf2 application i have to show database records in mobile and desktop versions with different criteria and conditions. For mobile version i have used `getUserMobileTable()` function and for desktop version it is `getUserDesktopTable()` .

for mobile version my action should work as

```
 public function userAction()
    {
             return new ViewModel(array('rowset' => $this->getUserMobileTable()->select()));
    }
```

for desktop version it action should work as

```
 public function userAction()
    {
             return new ViewModel(array('rowset' => $this->getUserDesktopTable()->select()));
    }
```

What should be logic to do it? Will i need to use `navigator.userAgent` in javascript to detect agent? If so then how? Please help i've no idea about it as i'm new to zend framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mobile Detect module](https://github.com/neilime/zf2-mobile-detect) to detect the user's device.

You could also do your logic in the same action and then select a different template like in this [example](http://samminds.com/2012/08/changing-the-view-template-view-script/)